# AndroidX and FragmentManager

Tags: visual-studio-2022, androidx, fragmentmanager

I am updating an older App to use AndroidX and moving it to VS2022. In my code, I have the following code:

```
AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.contentFrame, new MainScreenFragment());
ft.Commit();
```

I get the message that this is now obsolete. What is the proper way to do this now?
Is there a tutorial that explains the differences?

Thanks,
Dan

Furthermore, the second line generates the error:

```
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Resource.Id.contentFrame' and 'Resource.Id.contentFrame'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?